# Appending button to textarea

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I'm trying to do is append a button into a textarea's bottom right corner, like this:

[image]

However, I have no idea how I'd do this. Please help!

Answer (score 31):

You can use css to position the button there absolutely.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GwheP/

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

button{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
  right:10px;
}

textarea{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea name="" id="txt" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
  <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does the div need inline-block?

Comment: @Edward the default div display is `block` which forces the element to take up the full width available. [That would cause the button to be on the right of the page.](http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/GwheP/305/) `display:inline-block` take up only as much width as it needs -- it wraps around the object. You can use just `display:inline` but `inline-block` adds new lines before and after the element.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following,

```
<div id='container' style='width:600px; border:1px solid black;'>
    <textarea style='border-style:none none dashed none; border-color:black; width:100%; display:block;box-sizing:border-box;border-width:1px; margin-bottom:1px;'></textarea>
    <div style='width:100%; box-sizing:border-box; height:35px;padding:5px;'>
        <button style='float:right'>Lama mama
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also [here](http://jsfiddle.net/F4YKg/).

Comment: You can change it to css, but it doesn't actually matter for the example. :)

Answer (score 5):

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4EbGv/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <textarea name="somename" id="" cols="20" rows="10"></textarea>
    <div class="controls">
        <button>Post as Anonymous</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
}
.wrapper{
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    width: 600px;
}
.wrapper textarea{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e5e5e5 0%,#f2f2f2 100%);
    border:none;
    width:100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #999;
    resize: none;
}
.wrapper textarea:focus{
    outline: none;
}
.controls{
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: -6px;
}
button{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(77,77,77);
    border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this css help you for button to fit in textarea on right corner... because of aligning the background position.....

```
textarea {
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
padding-right: 20px;
background-image: url('http://www.isilo.com/support/manual/iSiloIP/img/gearIcon.gif');
background-position: top right;
background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

Comment: generally it's useful to explain, code only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, you can edit your post to explain why you have given this snippet as an answer and what does it add to existing answers. Thank you, and again welcome:)